# Check if/time Image loads ASP.net Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net

Ive looked around and havent seen anything on what I can do for my problem, so maybe someone here can help me. Basically I have an image (http://mysite.com/Sites/P/PA/25?encoding=UTF-8&b=100 note there is no file extension as this served through a script) and I want to check to see if this image returns an Image, or an error code like 404 or 403. I also want to record the response time of that. I am trying to make a web application that will monitor this software that displays the image, if it returns 404 error I know its down, if the load time is greater than 10 seconds I also know it may be down or some other action needs to be performed.

I thought about using `WebRequest.Create` but this wont return the time it took.

Any have any ideas on how I could implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Stopwatch around the snychronous WebRequest.DownloadFile method to track the timing.

An alternative would be to use a service that does this sort of thing and already has fancy reporting and notifications and such. Personally I use [BrowserMob](http://www.browsermob.com) for this sort of thing.